# WordPress Loop - skip posts without a thumbnail

Tags: wordpress

I want skip every post that has no thumbnail. The code does not work properly yet.

Actually the script doesn't show posts without a thumbnail - that's good, but in the loop the post with no thumbnail is still counted as a post.

So when i have for example 10 posts in my wordpress database. I want show 5 of them. But only the posts who has a thumbnail.

```
<ul>

    <?php

    $args = array(  'numberposts'  => 5,  
                    'orderby'      => 'date',  
                    'order'        => 'DESC',
                    'post_type'    => 'post',
                    'post_status'  => 'publish' 
                );

    $my_posts = get_posts( $args );
    global $post;
    foreach( $my_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 

    if ( !has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
        continue;             
    } else {

    ?>

        <li>
            <div class="clearfix" >
                <div class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-image-big'); ?></div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <p class="category"><?php the_category(', '); ?></p>
            </div>
        </li>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$args = array(  'numberposts'  => 5,  
                'orderby'      => 'date',  
                'order'        => 'DESC',
                'post_type'    => 'post',
                'post_status'  => 'publish' ,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                        'compare' => '!=',
                        'value' => ''
                    )
                )
            );
```

or this if checking for an empty string didn't work for you

```
$args = array(  'numberposts'  => 5,  
                'orderby'      => 'date',  
                'order'        => 'DESC',
                'post_type'    => 'post',
                'post_status'  => 'publish' ,
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
                        'compare' => '!=',
                        'value' => null
                    )
                )
            );
```